# Replace column values with column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is as follows:

```
ASD   ASP   TOF   SVC   OLIP
x    Nan    1     3      x
Nan   x    Nan    Nan    x
Nan  Nan    x     Nan    3
3    Nan    Nan   Nan    x
```

Also I have a dictionary which says

dict:

```
{1 : Trivial
 2 : Mild
 3 : Severe
}
```

Now I am trying to fill in and transform my dataframe in such a way that wherever there's x it should fill it with the column name and wherever there's number, it should fill it with the column name - dict value.

Expected dataframe out:

```
ASD        ASP   TOF          SVC         OLIP
ASD        Nan  TOF-Trivial  SVC-Severe   OLIP
Nan        ASP   Nan          Nan         OLIP
Nan        Nan   TOF          Nan         OLIP-Severe
ASD-Severe Nan   Nan          Nan         OLIP
```

I tried the following code

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(to_replace='x', value=df.columns.to_series())`
```

but it is giving me an error saying that AttributeError: Series object has no attribute columns.

I have to do the same stuff repetitively for multiple tables and I would really appreciate if any can help me with this problem.

Comment: Are your original `DataFrame` all `str` types? i.e. is the `Nan` actual `np.nan` or a sting `Nan`?

Comment: @yatu it is np.nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original `DataFrame` are all strings, you can do this:

```
   ASD  ASP  TOF  SVC OLIP
0    x  Nan    1    3    x
1  Nan    x  Nan  Nan    x
2  Nan  Nan    x  Nan    3
3    3  Nan  Nan  Nan    x

d = {
   1 : 'Trivial',
   2 : 'Mild',
   3 : 'Severe'
}

df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: {**{str(k): '{}-{}'.format(x.name, v) for k, v in d.items()}, 'nan': 'Nan'}.get(y.lower(), x.name)))

          ASD  ASP          TOF         SVC         OLIP
0         ASD  Nan  TOF-Trivial  SVC-Severe         OLIP
1         Nan  ASP          Nan         Nan         OLIP
2         Nan  Nan          TOF         Nan  OLIP-Severe
3  ASD-Severe  Nan          Nan         Nan         OLIP
```

If not, you can always coerce the type to `str` before you `apply` the second layer:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).apply(lambda y: {**{str(k): '{}-{}'.format(x.name, v) for k, v in d.items()}, 'nan': 'Nan'}.get(y.lower(), x.name)))
```

It might be more efficient if you can redefine your dictionary ahead of time:

```
d = {**{str(k): '{{}}-{}'.format(v) for k, v in d.items()}, 'nan': 'Nan'}

# {'1': '{}-Trivial', '2': '{}-Mild', '3': '{}-Severe', 'nan': 'Nan'}

# Or if you want the final result to be actually np.nan:

d = {**{str(k): '{{}}-{}'.format(v) for k, v in d.items()}, 'nan': np.nan}

# On python 2.7 you need to do this instead:

d = {str(k): '{{}}-{}'.format(v) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
d['nan'] = np.nan

# Or just redefine 'd' manually:

d = {'1': '{}-Trivial', '2': '{}-Mild', '3': '{}-Severe', 'nan': np.nan}

# After 'd' is setup define a custom function

def func(val, name):
    result = d.get(val.lower(), '{}')
    if type(result) == str:
        return result.format(name)
    else:
        return result

# call the custom function in the second layer of apply

df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).apply(lambda y: func(y.lower(), x.name)))

          ASD  ASP          TOF         SVC         OLIP
0         ASD  NaN  TOF-Trivial  SVC-Severe         OLIP
1         NaN  ASP          NaN         NaN         OLIP
2         NaN  NaN          TOF         NaN  OLIP-Severe
3  ASD-Severe  NaN          NaN         NaN         OLIP
```

Comment: NaN's are actual np.NaN and your function is filling column names in the place of NaN's also.

Comment: See my latest variant `d = {**{str(k): '{{}}-{}'.format(v) for k, v in d.items()}, 'nan': np.nan}` where `np.nan` is placed back.  Also `'nan'` is the `str` when coerced, so it should still work.

Comment: Looks like `d = {**{str(k): '{{}}-{}'.format(v) for k, v in d.items()}, 'nan': np.nan}` is not working as I am using python 2.7. Its giving me invalid syntax if I use **

Comment: I see.  Then you just change the definition of `d` originally to the result: `d = {'1': '{}-Trivial', '2': '{}-Mild', '3': '{}-Severe', 'nan': np.nan}`.  The problem was `items()` is not valid syntax in Python 2.7, and I'm not sure if `**` unpacking works either.

Comment: I've updated the answer that includes the python 2.7 variant.  It *should* work but I don't have python 2.7 handy to test the full thing.